# How to exclude database objects that include a certain Extended Property using SQL Compare 12?

Tags: sql-server, database, redgate, sqlcompare

I'm using SQL Compare to generate a script file to deploy to a production environment, but I can't get the Include or Exclude command line options to work with extended properties. Here is the commands I've tried so far.

Let me try to only include only objects with the extended property 'Feature'

```
SQLCompare.exe /scripts1:.\ /empty2 /Include:ExtendedProperty:Feature*
```

Ok so let me try to include everything with extended properties.

```
SQLCompare.exe /scripts1:.\ /empty2 /Include:ExtendedProperty:.*
```

Well then, let me try to do that again without regex.

```
SQLCompare.exe /scripts1:.\ /empty2 /Include:ExtendedProperty
```

Everytime I got nothing. No changes. So I tried including all the stored procedures and excluding the ones with extended properties.

```
SQLCompare.exe /scripts1:.\ /empty2 /Include:StoredProcedure /Exclude:ExtendedProperty:Feature.*
```

Still no luck. Has anyone used this feature before with success?